# grep erroring on globbing grep: f: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, grep

When I grep with globbing I get the error: "grep: f: no such file or directory" and it doesn't give me any valid resluts, just the error.
ie: `grep asdf *`
What I know:
It's only if I use * by itself
If I use the full path it works, ie '`grep asdf /home/user/*`'
It's grep egrep and fgrep
There is not a file named 'f' hidden or otherwise. 
It is any user, just in this one directory (the home directory for my main user)
If I create a file named 'f' I get grep: asdf: No such file or directory, (asdf being whatever I am grepping for and it hangs indefinitely. 
strace shows "open("f",O_RDONLY) no matter what I grep for.

This may not be the appropriate forum, but I use this command very often for work, it's automatic for me, and I hate having to redo the command with the full path. I can't find any answers anywhere.

Comment: Run `set -x` first and check the logs; you'll see what the `*` is globbing to, and thus what is *actually* being passed to `grep`.

Comment: Any chance there might be filenames that start with `-`? `grep asdf -- *` will make them be treated as, well, *filenames*, not other arguments. Still, that's not the only concern; broken symlinks could cause this error, for example.

Comment: ...that said, if you want a canonical and complete answer, we'll need a [mcve]: A script we can run to see the error ourselves. In this case, that means a script that actually creates the conditions under which the bug can manifest.

Comment: ...it's also possible you could be doing something you aren't showing us. Something like `files=$(ls *); grep asdf $files` will cause this bug (and the answer would be several different varieties of "don't do that").

Comment: This will happen if you e.g. have a file named `-e` in the current dir. `ls -l ./-*` sounds like a good idea.

Comment: You guys nailed it. There is a file named -ff. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, I'm new to participating in questions and not just reading. Is there a way to give you guys credit for helpful answers for reputation points or something?